# Get location of "source"ed script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to execute statements like (shell is bash)

```
/# source /workspace/scripts/script.sh
/workspace/scripts# source script.sh
```

Inside the script.sh I want to get its own location. (script.sh wont be in the PATH variable)

I could do this using `readlink -f $0` when run the script, but the same doesnt work when I `source` it.

I **dont** want the solution to be dependent on where I run the `source` command from. (otherwise `pwd` would have been enough)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to find the location reliably in 100% of all cases.
If you use **bash** your best bet is `$BASH_SOURCE` variable.
[This link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) is very helpful on this topic.

Comment: BASH_SOURCE did the trick. Thank you. (Using the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Since `script.sh` is in your path, you should be able to get it's full path using `which`. So, in the script, if `$0` isn't a full path, you can do `which $0`.

```
carabiner$ cat ~/bin/test.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo test - $0 $1
which $0

carabiner$ source test.sh
test - test.sh
test.sh is /home/zigdon/bin/test.sh
```

Comment: when you source a script $0 isnt pointing to the file anymore, it points to the shell thats running the "source script.sh"

Comment: I thought that was true too, but at least in `zsh`, it does actually point to the script sourced.

Comment: looks like the behavior is not same in bash though

Comment: You should use `type -a` in Bash instead of `which`.